# Setting WCF DataContract namespace using ContractNamespace attribute

Tags: .net, wcf

In designing my service, I decided that I wanted to customize the namespaces that appeared in the resulting WSDL.

For the DataContracts, i came across the [ContractNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.contractnamespaceattribute.aspx) attribute which seemed a nice shortcut alternative to setting the same namespace explicitly for every DataContract. My initial attempt looked like this:

```
[assembly:ContractNamespace("http://types.mycompany.com/2010/08/03")]
namespace MyCompany.MyContracts
{
    [DataContract]
    //...multiple datacontract classes here
}
```

To my surprise, this did not work. After much tinkering, I was only successful when I finally set the **ClrNamespace** property of the attribute equal to my CLR namespace (MyCompany.MyContracts in the example). So something like this

```
[assembly:ContractNamespace("http://types.mycompany.com/2010/08/03",
          ClrNamespace="MyCompany.MyContracts")]
```

My question is: why did this not work the first way? My expectation was that by not specifying a CLR namepsace, this attribute would affect all datacontracts assembly-wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, if the `ClrNamespace` is ommitted, then the contract namespace setting applies to objects in the global namespace.

Comment: Yeah that clears it up. I was not even familiar with the global namepsace