# Unable to deserialize XML post to WCF service. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, xml-deserialization

I have this class which is an input to my WCF service:

```
[DataContract]
public class LoginDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the method in my service interface (IUserServices):

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceException))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(LoginDTO))]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/login/", Method = "POST")]
    UserDTO LogIn(LoginDTO loginInfo);
```

Testing my service (using Postman) causes this error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to
>   deserialize XML body with root name 'LoginDTO' and root namespace ''
>   (for operation 'LogIn' and contract ('IUserServices', 
>   'http://tempuri.org/')) using DataContractSerializer. Ensure that the
>   type corresponding to the XML is added to the known types collection
>   of the service.

And I post this: (Content-Type => application/xml)

```
<LoginDTO>
    <Username>MyUsername</Username>
    <Password>MyPassword</Password>
</LoginDTO>
```

What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I marked @knyu's reply below as the answer because it addresses my immediate question. However, I decided to use a (proper) namespace for my types, so I added the [ContractNamespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408461/setting-wcf-datacontract-namespace-using-contractnamespace-attribute) attribute on my assembly that contains my DTOs. This then meant that my input XML will need to specify this namespace to be properly deserialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use namespaces for your entities, just set Namespace property of DataContract to empty string ("") and this should resolve this issue:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class LoginDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I'm definitely agreed with @Frank Fajardo and @Khurram Ali that using a proper namespace is a much better. But I don't actually know use-case scenario for service and there may be a scenario where you need to support some legacy clients or any other special requirements. Anyway, I hope my answer helps you to choose a right direction.